# Increment primitive local variable by calling different methods

Tags: java

I'm solving a college project in Java where we can't (or it is not recommended to...) use global variables. If we could use it it would be easier.
The thing is, I'm having troubles with a primitive variable (an integer that acts as a counter) that must be incremented every time that method is invoked.

For example:

```
public static void main... {
int rows = 0;
int[][] array = new int[24][2];
}

public static int readFile... (int rows, ...) {
...
...
...
rows++; (say here rows = 20);
return rows;
}

public static int addTeam... (int rows, ...) {
(method without for/while)
...
...
...
rows++;
return rows;
}
```

There are more methods.
Now I use a switch where if I press say 1, the first method is invoked and so on.
I want to press 2 three times, so that the second method gets invoked 4 times and the integer rows, thus, gets incremented until 23.

With a global variable this is easy, but without them how can I do it? No matter how many times I call the second method, the primitive (integer) "rows" won't change (I assume that's because it is a primitive, so it won't change like an array, which isn't a primitive).

I cannot use anything like lists, or objects (or even the this keyword), as this is an introduction to programming.

Comment: Not possible with primitives but a primitive array of size 1 can do the trick. Static/instance variable would help but as you say you can't use global variable.

Comment: You could change your design, why is every method `static`? If you don't want to change too much code, make every method an instance method and the class a singleton.

Comment: That really makes the trick!
Thank you!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch tbh every single exercise we have made (and every example our teachers presented to us) use static, so up until now we don't really know when static is more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Possible option is to use switch and assign row value each time after method called:

```
int rows = 0;
...
case 1:
    rows = method1(rows, _);
    break;
case 2:
    rows = method2(rows, _);
    break;
 //so on
```

Answer (score 0):

A more Object oriented solution: use a class to represent and save the data. Example, assuming you want to represent a collection of teams:

```java
public class Teams {

    private int rows = 0;
    private int[][] array = new int[24][2];  // TODO use constant

    public int size() {
        return rows;
    }

    public void readFile(...) {
        // possible in a loop
        ...
        rows++;// call or addTeam(...);
    }

    public void addTeam(...) {
        ...
        rows++;
    }

    // more methods
}
```

Not ideal, based on questions code. (e.g. have a class `Team` to represent each team, using `List` instead of arrays, ...)